# Sending signals to long-running processes (AWK, DD)

Tags: awk, process, signals

I'm familiar that DD command doesn't produce output while running. However, if I send a USR1 signal to it, it can print current state.

Can I do the same with AWK? Prints its variables, register signal_handler?

Answer (score 5):

You can't rely on this behavior across platforms, even for `dd`.  [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) doesn't specify a response to SIGUSR1, and indeed your `dd` process will die if you try it on [OSX](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2006/06/11/printing-dd-status/) or [BSD](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-standards/2011-March/002198.html), or even sometimes on [embedded Linux (Busybox)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=654872).  Using `SIGUSR1` on `dd` in this way appears to be a GNU extension.  In practice, on most desktop Linux systems you'll be able to do this.

Similarly, if you're using GNU `awk`, you *may* be able to send it a `SIGUSR1` to get some GNU-specific internal state info.  In this case it doesn't print to stdout, but to a file.  Awk versions that support this are GNU `awk` [4.1.0 and later](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/QM51VPAlw4I) if run with the `-p` (`--profile`) flag, or [3.1 and later](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_162.html) when compiled and run as `pgawk`.

For details of what the signals do, see the `gawk` man page ([version 3.1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gawk) or [version 4.1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html)), and search for "Signals".

Note that it's less certain that your desktop Linux is running GNU awk than GNU `dd`; [`mawk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mawk) is another awk I've seen running on desktop Linux.

Comment: Note: The provided man-page link speaks only about `pgawk`, the GNU `awk` spinoff: *"pgawk accepts two signals."*. - But since the features of `pgawk` merged into the newer versions 4.x of GNU `awk` you can find it in the official manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html - The feature is used in context of dynamic profilling.

Comment: @Janis: Nicely spotted!  I've updated the answer to include some version info.